# wwwroot serving pages not MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently working on an Asp.Net 5 / mvc 6 app. I was running the beta5 release and updated to beta7. I have noticed my index page is loading from the wwwroot directory (I started the app with an index page in the wwwroot and am now using mvc, making the index in the wwwroot redundant)

All of my mvc views were loading correctly prior to the update to beta7, I ideally do not want to go back to beta5.

I have included mvc in the Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",//optional id
                    defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                    );
            });
```

Project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7"

  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after upgrading to beta8 and running dnvm upgrade this has resolved my issue. I believe my configuration was not entirely in line. Thanks to meligy & juergen-gutsch for their answers, very useful to know.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by the way. It's allowed in StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `Startup` class ("Startup.cs" file under src/project-name), in the `Configure()` method, this line:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

probably comes before:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => ... );
```

You can change the order so that `UseMvc(...)` comes before `UseStaticFiles(...)`, but note that this means MVC will try to handle all requests to images etc as well even if it doesn't need to.

You can also just change-the-name-of / move / remove the index file now that don't need it anyway.

Comment: So I tried to move the UseMvc(...) before the UseStaticFiles(...) and this did not make any difference. I am going to try what @juergen-gutsch suggested to try and isolate the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a complete new ASP.NET 5 project and compare the project.json and the startup.cs with that files from your updated project.

This is the best option to see what is wrong with your current configuration.